# Understanding differential equations — why can't all ODEs be integrated?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm in the process of learning about differential equations and something keeps bothering me. I know the idea that a differential equation relates a function and its derivatives and I can do simple manipulations with them (separation of variables, etc ), but I find this intuition very unsatisfying.

For example, consider

$$\frac{\mathrm{dy} }{\mathrm{d} x} = 2x$$

which has the solution $x^2+c$. That solution was obtained by just by integrating. What I don't have is the intuition behind more difficult equations, why can't they just be integrated?

Comment: Usually  because the right hand side involves, not only $x$, but also $y$? But it can be integrated if variables are separable, for instance.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I was still unsure and wanted clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you a parallel, not all integrations can be expressed in a neat form. For example, if you try to compute the following

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\sin x}{x}$$

You can't express $y(x)$ using simple functions in a closed form. However, it is still possible to integrate it using *numerical* methods. These are more to solve IVPs rather than analytically solve ODEs. The process you'd go about is to first define the IVP, say as follows

$$y' = \frac{\sin x}{x}$$
$$y(1) = 0.5$$

And then solve it using any of the many available approaches. For example an Eulerian approach would follow these steps

$$y(x+\Delta x) = y(x) + \Delta x\cdot y' = y(x) + \frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot\Delta x$$

Now starting with $x=1$ and with a particular $\Delta x$, you can find any point of the form $y(x+n\Delta x)$ by repeating this process recursively. The smaller your $\Delta x$, the finer you can find $y$, but the more time it will take. There are of course some functions this doesn't work as well on( functions which have sharp oscillatory behaviour), and hence there are other methods to solve them